# What type should I store IP addresses for MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I was going to use `varchar(20)`, but I was wondering what should if I should do INT and strip off the periods instead. What would be better and why?

Comment: It depends on what operations will you perform on the data.

Comment: You can't just strip off the periods or you would have to pad each octet with zeroes so they're all 3 chars long. Otherwise the IP's 192.168.45.5 and 192.168.4.55 would look the same. When people suggest using an int (32 bits) they mean you take each octet (8 bits each) and pack them together into a single int.

Comment: for ipv4 + ipv6 hybrid, VARBINARY(16)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I presume you're only interested in IPv4 addresses, not IPv6.

I would use an `INT UNSIGNED` for the column, and then use `INET_ATON` and `INET_NTOA` to convert back and forth between the textual representation and the int value.

```
mysql> SELECT INET_ATON('192.168.10.50');
+----------------------------+
| INET_ATON('192.168.10.50') |
+----------------------------+
|                 3232238130 |
+----------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT INET_NTOA(3232238130);
+-----------------------+
| INET_NTOA(3232238130) |
+-----------------------+
| 192.168.10.50         |
+-----------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 3):

store IPV4 as int unsigned

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet-aton

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet-ntoa

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know those functions existed.

Comment: @ajreal - binary or x2 bigint unsigned

Comment: I always see a lot of advices of storing IPs as integers without explanation why to do that. One more. Can you explain **why** is int better here than (var)char?

Comment: @zerkms - simple scenario, i want to log user activity so let's assume we have a log table of 10 million rows (it's tiny i know). using a char we get 10 million * 15 bytes = 143MB of IP data alone. 10 million rows * 4 bytes = 38MB of IP data (105MB difference). So you'd get approx 4 times as many values buffered using an INT. Why would using a char be better here in your opinion ?

Comment: @f00: because we don't need to transform it back with inet_ntoa() to display. And, yes, the size is an argument. Not very important but it is.

Comment: @zerkms - i'd much rather my query performance across large volumes of data be efficient and faster than worry about a simple data transform which i'd do in my presentation tier anyway.

Comment: @f00: almost all the searches through int and char-presented IPs will be the same performant.

Comment: @f00: give a sample when they will be different dramatically. How can I show you something that doesn't exist? :-))) Give a sample of serch through ip int-based that is impossible to perform over string-based ones (i know they are, but not sure you will give me a sample of them).

Comment: @zerkms Search for all addresses in subnet 10.0.0.123/26. Easy to do as an unsigned integer, very costly to do if stored as a string.

Answer (score 0):

If you're really concerned about saving space, you can pack it into a 4-byte int.  Each block of an IPv4 IP address can have 256 possible values, which just happens to be the range of a single byte.

-- Edit -->  What I just described can be done with the mysql functions f00 linked in his answer

However, storing it as a string will save a bit of coding time.  Honestly, unless you're doing this on a very large scale, the optimization from a denser storage format won't matter.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you already switch from MySQL to MariaDB or people (like me) did research on how to store IP addresses in MariaDB.

There is a new datatype known as INET6, it works for both IP version.

Documentation can be found [here](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/inet6/).