# What is the ideal datatype to store IP address in a mysql table?

Tags: mysql, sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What type should I store IP addresses for MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4590192/what-type-should-i-store-ip-addresses-for-mysql)

One single datatype which can accommodate both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses. I want to store IP addresses to limit the number of profiles that a person can make from his/her machine in my website.

Comment: i would recommend integer and then parse it

Comment: Only IPv4, or IPv6 as well? Just an IP or also its subnet mask?

Comment: some similar topics in SO recommend varchar... wat abt that?

Comment: both IPv4 and IPv6, and only IP address

Comment: I second the integer reccommendation.   For example, 127.000.000.001 as string is the same as 127.0.0.1.   Stored as strings, you'll need to do extra processing to dupe check the addresses

Comment: I don't think 128bit ipv6 address will fit into a int. See http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/904/mysql-data-type-for-128-bit-integers for some info

Answer (score 17, accepted):

IPv4 addresses use 32 bits (4 bytes), IPv6 addresses use 128 bits (16 bytes). Thus, you can store their binary representation in `BINARY(16)` or `VARBINARY(16)` fields.

Also see my answer to the question [IP address storing in mysql database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6427786/ip-address-storing-in-mysql-database/6427883#6427883). It also provides comments why you would choose one over the other.

Comment: the storage and retrieval works cool... but am not sure whether it will work cool for the intended purpose that I mentioned in the question

Comment: `varbinary(16)` seems to be the best choice. `INET6_ATON('172.32.x.x')` can convert both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses into `blob`. The same can be converted back using `INET6_NTOA`. There won't be any need to juggle code between v4 and v6; at least for storage and retrieval.

Comment: how to translate this varbinary back into the readable form ?

Comment: @Abhi there's utility function in many languages, for example in PHP there's `inet_pton`/`inet_ntop`

Comment: careful, you can **NOT** reliably store both ipv4 and ipv6 addresses in BINARY(16) - sure, you can *guess* that if the last 12 bytes are null's, then it's *probably* a ipv4 address, but with this guessing, about 4.2 billion ipv6 addresses will be falsely identified as ipv4!  (on the other hand, 4.2 billion ipv6 addresses is about 0.00000002% of the total ipv6 space, but it's still a bug, just one presumably very hard to hit)

Answer (score 0):

A trie datatype would be optimal. There is uncompressed and compressed data struture from that type.