# IP Address - MySQL data type

Tags: mysql

I have a database with Country-IP addresses.

My table has two fields.

```
LBound, tinyint
UBound, tinyint
```

When I query the table like this:

```
select * from allowed where '129.250.224.1' BETWEEN lbound AND ubound
```

I get 3 results:

```
12.205.104.0    13.16.137.9
129.250.2.43    129.250.3.137
129.250.16.47   129.253.255.255
```

But I only want to return:

```
129.250.16.47   129.253.255.255
```

Is this a data type issue? If so, what datatype should I be using?

Answer (score 1):

You could use

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html

```
 INETT_ATON
```

and

```
  INET_NTOA
```

eg :

```
 SELECT INET_ATON('10.0.5.9');
    -> 167773449
```

In this way you can convert the IP in a number properly and filter correctly

Comment: How do I use it with this?

die("select * from allowed where '$ADDRESS' BETWEEN lbound AND ubound");

Comment: How do I use it on Lbound & UBound?

Comment: NM. Got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `inet_aton` function to convert IP address text into numeric value and compare. Like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM allowed
WHERE inet_aton('129.250.224.1') BETWEEN inet_aton(lbound) AND inet_aton(ubound);
```

Regarding which type to use to store the IP address, I'd use UNSIGNED INT or VARBINARY(16).

---

Related question -

- [What type should I store IP addresses for MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4590192/what-type-should-i-store-ip-addresses-for-mysql)
- [What is the ideal datatype to store IP address in a mysql table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8157324/what-is-the-ideal-datatype-to-store-ip-address-in-a-mysql-table)